# How to Connect to Specific Domain Controller?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller

I have one domain controller (DC) in one location and a failover DC in another location. For some reason, there are a few computers in the first location when logining into the domain login into DC2 (the failover DC) rather than DC1 (the "main" DC). Anyone know why that is and how I can force these computers to login into DC1?

Comment: Do you have active directory sites configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure Sites and Services in AD. You need to create your subnets, and associate them with sites. Then, when a machine tries to contact AD, it's subnet will tell it what site it's in, and it will start with the closest DC(s) to it, which would be in its site.

Answer (score 4):

AD sites are meant to be used for this. Or you could mess with the SRV records and the respective priorities of the DCs.

Comment: You second suggestion isn't a good idea for most scenarios - if you make DC1 a higher priority, you're enforcing that most/all users at site 2 will try using it instead of their local, DC2.

Comment: absolutely true! I was assuming that there's only one fail-over direction rather than crosswise fail-over which would be the better solution as is the case with properly set up AD sites.

Comment: Agreed. As you said first, AD Sites is where it's at. It's best to use the tools available, don't try to work around them.